# What is the request source-IP-address when it is originating from a docker container

Tags: networking

I work within a corporation that has very strict security policies.

I am running a single docker container consisting of an asp.net core 3.1 mvc web-app. It is based on the default asp.net debian 10 image provided by microsoft.
I have only installed docker engine - so no docker compose - and have not had to do any additional set-up/config, but run the container by a simple command:

```
docker run -p port-x:port-y imagename:tag
```

when I navigate to http://host-Ip i can access the web-app from my windows dev machine.

However, the host is RHEL running in a very restricted enterprise network.

Now I need to connect to an external domain from within the container but that can only happen via an internal proxy.
The proxy team requires the source ip-address.

I have 2 questions:

1. would that be the host (RHEL) ip address?
2. Is there a way to test this (I cannot/not allowed to install custom software/libs into RHEL and have access to basic + limited set)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this: The source ip-address is the RHEL host ip-address where the container is running